# Keep references to nodes of serde_json tree

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a Rust problem and would like some advice: I use serde_json to create a json structure dynamically in a loop. Every iteration creates one Value:Object node and adds it as a sibling to the previous node. Sometimes however  (decided at runtime) I need to add the data from the current run as a child to the node created in the previous iteration.

I try to keep a reference to the node of the previous iteration and because I need to add children it needs to be mutable. This conflicts with the reference to the node in my json structure.

I tried to wrap the node into Rc RefCell  but that seems to move issue from compile time to runtime. How would I solve this? Any hints appreciated!

Here is an example of the expected output:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "name3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "name4"
    }
  ]
}
```

which should have been generated from the following input:

```
- name1
- name2 
    - name3
- name4
```

Here is my reduced example code:

```rust
use serde_json::{Value, Map};
use std::borrow::Borrow;


fn node(name: &str) -> Map<String, Value>{
    let mut node:Map<String, Value> = Map::new();
    node.insert("name".to_string(), Value::String(name.to_string()));
    return node;
}

fn main(){
  let mut root:Map<String, Value> = Map::new();
  root.insert("children".to_string(), Value::Array(Vec::new()));

  let mut parent:&mut Vec<Value>;
  
  if let Some(Value::Array(array))=root.get_mut("children"){
        parent=array;
  } else {
      std::process::exit(1);
  }
  
  // First iteration
  {
    let node = node("1");
    parent.push(Value::Object(node));
  }
  
  // Second iteration
  {
    let node = node("2");
    let mut array  = Vec::new();
    array.push(Value::Object(node));

    if let Some(Value::Object(obj))=parent.last_mut(){
      obj.insert("children".to_string(), Value::Array(array));
      if let Some(Value::Array(array))=obj.get_mut("children"){
        parent=array;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Third iteration
  {
    let node = node("3");
    //parent.push(Value::Object(node));
  }
  
  
  
  let json = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&*root.borrow()).unwrap();
  println!("{}", json);
}
```

[Link to the Rust Playgound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f026f9c4c768055994a062dfe40be13a)

Comment: why don't you simply use a hashmap ? it would be simpler with a code example of what you are really doing.

Comment: I added a code example. It lacks the parsing code and is reduced to the actual issue.

Comment: honestly I tried follow what you want https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5deab5f924b716d8cfeedbf17ddf3b3c but that bullshit and I don't understand why you are doing this, I don't get why you want construct such evil code, my answer is you are doing something wrong, but without context we can't help you in any way. No one should "construct" a json value. have a rust data structure and just convert it to json at the very end.

Comment: Like something like that but that still ugly since I have no understanding of why you are doing this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eddf3cbed174f195b848d1be49d91b9d

Comment: I got two different solutions on the Rust forums: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-keep-a-reference-to-nodes-of-serde-json-tree/92913

Comment: I would appreciate you don't cross posting without noticing us so I don't loose my time.

Answer (score 1):

As parasyte and quinedot very helpfully pointed out on the Rust forums this is an example for a non-lexical lifetime case that is not yet covered by the compiler.

The solution is either to compile with Rust nightly and the polonius feature enabled or to employ the following workaround (as contributed by quinedot):

```
let parent = {
        let node = node("2");
        let mut array = Vec::new();
        array.push(Value::Object(node));

        if let Some(Value::Object(obj)) = parent.last_mut() {
            obj.insert("children".to_string(), Value::Array(array));
            if let Some(Value::Array(array)) = obj.get_mut("children") {
                array
            } else {
                parent
            }
        } else {
            parent
        }
    };
```

Comment: A third alternative _may_ be building the structure bottom-up (e.g. beginning with the leaf nodes, then wrapping them in the parent nodes, all the way up). It may not be applicable, but I think in the general case, you can always reverse the construction order.